# Spring-boot-starter-minio does not work after migrating to spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, minio

I have an app using spring boot and minio. I use this dependency for minio:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jlefebure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-minio</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I migrated my app from spring boot 2.3.8.RELEASE to spring boot 3.0.2, I got the following error during the start up:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jlefebure.spring.boot.minio.MinioService' in your configuration.
```

According to this link:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files

In spring boot 3.0.2 the spring.factories file must be replaced with this file: "INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports". However, this dependency still uses spring.facatories file to auto configure the beans and I think that's why after migration it doesn't work anymore.

So is there any way to get spring-boot-starter-minio work with spring boot 3? or is there any way to manually create the MinioService bean?

Comment: Import the configuration yourself (or copy it). However that would probably require some additional work with mapping configuration properties etc.

Comment: I added something like this: @Import({MinioConfiguration.class, MinioNotificationConfiguration.class, MinioMetricConfiguration.class}) on my spring boot main class, but it gives this error during start up "Failed to process import candidates for configuration class".

Comment: WIthout seeing more information on that error that isn't really helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will update my question with the details. Just wanted to know when you said "copy it" you mean I should manually create MinioConfiguration class in my app? I mean could you explain more your solution please.

Comment: I said import if (or copy it). If you copy it you will probably run into the same problems. Only importing it will probably not be enough as there is probably also some `@EnableConfigurationProperties` needed for this to bind/create the necessary properties object (you basically need to mimic the auto-configuration for this but then manually).

Comment: I tried what you suggested and updated my question, but again the same error. could you look at my updated  question please?

Comment: There must be more in the starter/dependencies that create the service.

Comment: MinioService has defined in this package com.jlefebure.spring.boot.minio. I didn't get what to do.

Comment: There must be configuration that creates that services.

Comment: I can't initialize this class in my config file, because it has been defined in the external jar as a @service class which is part of this dependency <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-minio</artifactId> and I don't have any control on this class.

Comment: I yield. As I stated you should mimic the full configuration of the starter (including any additional configurations being loaded, or additional component-scans being registered etc.).

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, I feel I made you angry. Do you mean that I should  copy the whole class of MinioService which existed in that dependency and create that in my application again?